How to modify (add color to) "Error:" prefix when returning an error?
I have this code:
// main.rs
fn main() -> Result<(), error::ParseError> {
    foo()?;
    Ok(())
}

Assumed that foo() return error::ParseError::EmptyLine.
// error.rs
use std::{error::Error, fmt};
use colored::Colorize;

pub enum ParseError {
    EmptyLine,
}

impl fmt::Display for ParseError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        error_handler(self, f)
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for ParseError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        error_handler(self, f)
    }
}

impl Error for ParseError {}

fn error_handler(error: &ParseError, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    match error {
        ParseError::EmptyLine => writeln!(f, "{}", "input is an emtpy line".red().bold()),
    }
}

Output after cargo run:
Error: input is an emtpy line

The problem is that part "input is an empty line" is red, as I want, but "Error:", which Rust adds by default, doesn't change color. I can't find any way to modify this prefix or remove it.
How can I do that? I would prefer to do it without additional libraries if at all possible.

Does this answer your question? How to remove default "Error" from main Result handler Essentially don't simply return the error from main since Error: is part of that handling; handle the error yourself so you can print it as you like.

@kmdreko Looks like yes.  Error: prefix is added by the Termination implementation for Result. Thx. Can't find it by myself.
Answer will be implemet Termination with custom Result type
